# Same ItemSource, but has another View each listboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

Here is my situation:

A ObservableCollection is exist and a series of listbox in a window has showing their bound data.

```
public Records myRecents;

//...

this.lbToday.ItemsSource = myRecents;
this.lbYesterday.ItemsSource = myRecents;
this.lbBefore2Days.ItemsSource = myRecents;
this.lbLast7Days.ItemsSource = myRecents;
this.lbLast30Days.ItemsSource = myRecents;
```

And now, I want to applie each listboxes to different filtered view.

```
this.lbToday.Items.Filter = delegate(object item)
{
    return ((RecordItem)item).IsToday();
};
```

A problem is, the filter applied all listboxes which using same itemsource.(in this case, the 
'myRecents')

How can I applying differ filterings each listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different `ListCollectionViews` for each one of your ListBoxes

```
this.lbToday.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(myRecents); 
this.lbYesterday.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(myRecents); 
this.lbBefore2Days.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(myRecents);
this.lbLast7Days.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(myRecents); 
this.lbLast30Days.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(myRecents);
```